# Unset filter from user state

Tags: session, filter

I like to unset my search filter that is saved in the user state.
I have a search input with id `filter_search`
This is the code to save the filter.

```
$context = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
$this->setState('filter.search', $context);
```

Now In another function I would like to unset this filter_search state.
How Do I do this?

I already tried this:

```
$session = Factory::getSession();
$session->clear('.filter.search', 'filter_search');
```

And

```
$this->setState('filter.search', "");
```

But my input field stays filled.

This is my `filter_customers.xml`

```
<fields name="filter">
        <field name="search" type="text" hint="COM_MYDESTINY_SEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT" label="COM_USERS_FILTER_SEARCH_DESC" class="js-stools-search-string uk-search-input"/>
</fields>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was

```
$app->setUserState($this->context . '.filter.search', "");
```

The context can be changed so you can also change filters from different models